# Discord bot on heroku Push error while deploy

Tags: python, heroku, bots

I made a small bot for my personnal use in discord and I wanted to host it on Heroku but I had trouble with deploying the application, the code is on a private repository on github

I've already made `Procfile`, `requirement.txt`and `runtime.txt` 
Several month ago I made anothers discord.py bot (async version of discord.py) and I've used the same files as I want to use now.

My `Procfile` : 
`worker: python3 Main.py`

My `requirements.txt` :

```
discord.py==1.2.3
```

My `runtime.txt` : 
`python-3.7.4`

My python code

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")
client.remove_command('help')

#Event

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Kitsune Bot : Online")



for files in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if files.endswith('.py'):
        try:
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{files[:-3]}')
            print("{} is running !".format(files))
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)     



client.run(<myToken>)
```

The expected result is the bot going online and responding to all my function call, however the actual result is an error while deploying the app on heroku :

````
-----> Installing python-3.7.4

-----> Installing pip

-----> Installing requirements with pip

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requirements needs to be a `file` not a txt file
you can do it by doing `touch requirements`